# Deleting photo saved in folder using room database in android

Tags: java, android

I am taking photo using default camera in mobile. After that saving the photo in specific path in folder which path have been created using File class. In Room database I have storing only the path of image. Now, I added delete method to delete specific photo. I am using following query to delete,

```
 @Query("DELETE FROM record_table WHERE photo_path = photoPath")
     int deletePhotoPath(String photoPath);
```

below methods are used for deleting photo(DataRepository.class)

```
 public void  deletePhotoPath(String photoPath){
        new deletePhotoPathAsyncTask(RecordDao).execute(photoPath);
    }

    private class deletePhotoPathAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void>{
        public deletePhotoPathAsyncTask(RecordDao dao) {
            RecordDao=dao;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(final String... strings) {
            int photoPathDeleted=RecordDao.deletePhotoPath(strings[0]);
            Log.d("deletePhotoPath"," Photo Path"+photoPathDeleted+strings[0]);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I am calling delete method as below(MyActivity.class),

```
 HolderData.deletePhotoPath(photopathArrayList.get(positionOfCurrentViewPhoto));
```

In HolderData class I have following method to call delete method from database(HolderData.class),

```
public static void deletePhotoPath(String photoPath){
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "deletPhotoPath:"+photoPath);
        dataRepository.deletePhotoPath(photoPath);
    }
```

But my photo is not getting deleted. Logcats inside delete method works fine.
Doesn't know to delete photo. And How do I reflect the change in my design.
Anybody help me to solve this..Already Surfed a lot but not able to find a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Don`t forget to add the colon when you refer to the argument parameter in your query:

```
DELETE FROM record_table WHERE photo_path = :photoPath
```

2. Before deleting the link from Room extract it, create a File instance programmatically and call "delete" method on that instance:

```
File file = new File("path to your file");
file.delete();
```